# Text box that only accepts numbers in Racket's GUI library

Tags: user-interface, racket

In Racket's GUI library, I can use a [`text-field%`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text-field_.html?q=text-field%25) to add a single line textbox to a window. However, I would like to limit this text box to only allow integers to be typed.

One possible way to handle this is to insert a callback whenever a letter is typed, to add it into the text box ourselves. The `text-field%` class has methods `get-value` and `set-value`, but there are only used for programmatic modification of the text box, and not as a callback.

Another way would be to pass in a regex for allowable characters or strings in the text box, but this does not seem to be supported either.

So, is there any way to create a text field in Racket that will only allow the user to type in integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that there already is a solution to this problem on [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/GUI_component_interaction#Racket). What you 'can' do in a text box is set a callback that is called whenever the user types. Then, you can use `set-value` to remove the character that you didn't want there. The resulting `text-field%` object would look like this (taking it from the link):

```
(new text-field% [label "Value"] [parent frame] [init-value "0"]
     [callback
      (λ (f ev)
        (define v (send f get-value))
        (unless (string->number v)
          (send f set-value (regexp-replace* #rx"[^0-9]+" v ""))))]))
```

Where frame is the frame you are putting in the text box, say:

```
(define frame (new frame% [label "Demo Frame"))
```